# Spring dynamically choosing between data sources (alternative to ThreadLocal)

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-data, spring-batch

I've read about [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) and the standard ways to bind a datasource dynamically in [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/):

```
public class CustomerRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

   @Override
   protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
      return CustomerContextHolder.getCustomerType();
   }
}
```

It uses a `ThreadLocal` context holder to "set" the DataSource:

```
public class CustomerContextHolder {

   private static final ThreadLocal<CustomerType> contextHolder = 
            new ThreadLocal<CustomerType>();

   public static void setCustomerType(CustomerType customerType) {
      Assert.notNull(customerType, "customerType cannot be null");
      contextHolder.set(customerType);
   }

   public static CustomerType getCustomerType() {
      return (CustomerType) contextHolder.get();
   } 

   // ...
}
```

I have a quite complex system where threads are not necessarily in my control, say:

- Scheduled EJB reads a job list from the database
- For each Job it fires a Spring (or Java EE) batch job.
- Each job have its origin and destination databases (read from a central database).
- Multiple jobs will run in parallel
- Jobs may be multithreaded.
- `ItemReader` will use the origin data source that was set for that specific job (origin data source must be bound to some repositories)
- `ItemWriter` will use the destination data source that was set for that specific job (destination data source must also be bound to some repositories).

So I'm feeling somewhat anxious about `ThreadLocal`, specially, I'm not sure if the same thread will be used to handle multiple jobs. If that happens origin and destination databases may get mixed.

How can I "store" and bind a data source dynamically in a safe way when dealing with multiple threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to setup Spring to play nice with my setup and inject the desired `DataSource`, so I've decided to handle that manually.

### Detailed solution:

1. I changed my repositories to be prototypes so that a new instance is constructed every time that I wire it:

   ```
   @Repository
   @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   ```
2. I've introduced new `setDataSource` and `setSchema` methods in top level interfaces / implementations that are supposed to work with multiple instances / schemas.
3. Since I'm using [spring-data-jdbc-repository](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/spring-data-jdbc-repository) my `setDataSource` method simple wraps the `DataSource` with a new `JdbcTemplate` and propagate the change.

   ```
   setJdbcOperations(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
   ```
4. My implementation is obtaining the `DataSources` directly from the application server:

   ```
   final Context context = new InitialContext();
   final DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/" + dsName);
   ```
5. Finally, for multiples schemas under the same database instance, I'm logging in with a special user (with the correct permissions) and using a Oracle command to switch to the desired schema:

   ```
   getJdbcOperations().execute("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = " + schema);
   ```

While this goes against the Dependency inversion principle it works and is handling my concurrency requirements very well.

Comment: do you have any sample implementaion code ? facing the same issue in bring spring batch work with multiple schema